# Locking or freezing the TODAY() formula

Tags: google-sheets

I've looked around in the community about locking or freezing a current date, but I'm still having issues.

That if i have marked tick on cell "C2 then today's date "11-11-2020" will auto populate into cell D2 i.e,. 11-11-2020 and that date will automatically changed to 12-11-2020 on very next day. Because of =TODAYS() function.

My goal is to lock a date that's triggered by marking a tick and have that current date freeze until the tick is removed.

My current sheet below  shows the 10-11-2020 date which will change tomorrow and needs to be "locked" once the tick is marked and remain 10-11-2020  until the tick is removed

Could anyone help me correct formula to what it needs to be?

```
=IF(C2="Checked",TODAY(),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*There is no way to turn off the recalculation feature of Google Sheets formulae. You can however achieve this with an `onEdit()` trigger.*

#### More Information:

Google Sheets allows you to write small scripts which get executed when the Sheet that it is connected to is edited. You can read more about these triggers, named simple triggers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

In your situation, as the `TODAY()` function will ***always*** be recalculated whenever the sheet is reopened, it is of no use. Instead, what we can do, is have the cell in column `D` update with the current date when the corresponding cell in column `C` is ticked.

#### Setting up the Trigger:

From the `Tools > Script editor` menu item, you can create a function with the following code:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (e.range.getColumn() != 3 || sheet.getName() != "Data") {
    return;
  }
  var cell = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 4);
  if (e.value == "TRUE") {  
    cell.setNumberFormat("d-mmm-yyyy").setValue(new Date());
  }
  else if (e.value == "FALSE") {
    cell.clear();
  }
}
```

And press save.

**Rundown of this function:**

- Checks to see if the cell edited is in column `C`

  - Halts the function if this is not true
- If the cell is checked, it gets the adjaecent cell in column D and sets its number formating to the format `11-Nov-2020`

  - Sets today's date in the cell
- If the cell is unchecked, it will clear the ajaecent cell in column `D`.

Now, you can edit your sheet. Each time a cell in column `C` is checked, column `D` will populate with today's date.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Rafa Guillermo, Thank you for giving the solution but it does not remove the date after unchecked the box.

Comment: Thank you for further addition but it still not removing dates after unchecked the box.

Comment: @Learning [I can confirm that it does](https://imgur.com/HthTt22) - make sure you have saved the script after updating it.

Comment: Yes I changed the False to Unchecked that was issue. Thank you so much