# Automatic addition of date on cell edition (Without script)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on making it possible to see the date when a cell has been edited on a sheet, but I can only think of NOW and TODAY formulas which change every time the sheet is recalculated. I cannot use scripts as my company blocked their use.

Any idea if it is do-able?

Here is what I did for now but cannot think of a way for the date to stay when the data has been written in "B" Column.
Here is the formula I added in C2 `=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",today()))`
It works but the date will change.
[image]

Comment: Doing it without a script is not possible.
You might find further informations here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788093/locking-or-freezing-the-today-formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an ideal way(as done by scripts) but this should serve the purpose in your use-case here. Try this out & see if its feasible for ya:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A,if(B2:B="",now(),B2:B),))
```

- `Enable iterative calculation` in sheets setting as in screenshot
- Format the `Column B` to timestamp format

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can also try: `=if(isblank(B2),,lambda(x,x)(now()))`  This does not need iterative calculation enabled whilst this is *non-arrayformula* solution.

Comment: I just changed a bit your formula rockinfreakshow as I am using data but I didn't think of the Iterative calculation and I will try it on using `=arrayformula(IF(A2:A<>"" ,if(B2:B="",now(),B2:B),))`. Accepting this answer as most helpful for me